# PyQt5 setText by object name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a grid of buttons with each button residing inside it's own groupbox. I want to dynamically update these button's labels.

It's not clear to me how to address these buttons after being created in iteration and is there a way to just address their object names.

The documentation that I've read doesn't appear to include any methods for settext via object name.  Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

PyQt5, Python 3.6

Comment: [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html).

Comment: @ekhumoro.  I'm not sure what you are suggesting. Each of my buttons are inside a QGroupBox as a way to add a tight label above each button. I'm also hoping to change the background color of individual boxes in response to events (without changing the color of the button itself as I also want to do that as an indicator for different events).  Can I assign an integer id to the QGroupBoxes the same way I would actual button widgets?  Currently they are added to QGridLayout.

Comment: Each button will have its group-box as parent, so you can access it with `button.parent()`. The button-group provides a unified way to access a set of buttons (using ids) and handle all their signals via a single connection. It's just a simple convenience class that saves you having to manage the buttons yourself. (PS: you can also [use Qt Designer to set up button-groups](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41861892/984421)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have put a name to the widget with the function:

```
your_widget.setObjectName(your_name)
```

You can access it through the parent through the `findChild` function:

```
your_parent_widget.findChild(name_class, your_name)
```

Example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        for i in range(10):
            pushButton = QPushButton(self)
            pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton{}".format(i))
            pushButton.setText(str(i))
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(pushButton)

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.setInterval(1000)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.updateText)
        timer.start()

    def updateText(self):
        for i in range(10):
            child = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton{}".format(i))
            counter = int(child.text())
            child.setText(str(counter+1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```